# QT , my form was hidden after calling setWindowFlags() in my slots

Tags: qt

I just want to disable form's close button while doing a task(by QThread), So I connected the thread's signal "started()" and "finished()" to my two slots, for controlling my form's close button.

```
//...
m_pTestThread = new TestThread();

connect(m_pTestThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(onThreadStart()));
connect(m_pTestThread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onThreadFinish()));

m_pTestThread->start();
//...
```

```
void QTest::onThreadStart()
{
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & (~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint));
}

void QTest::onThreadFinish()
{
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
}
```

After the thread started, my form was hidden... that is strange.

So I call `show()` after `setWindowFlags()` function to avoid this problem,
but still don't know why this happened...

Is this the expected behaviour? Should I call `show()` after `setWindowFlags()`?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for `setWindowFlags` [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> Note: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a
> window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make
> the widget visible again..